# Excel quits on Worksheet_Change Event

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Can someone please point out what's wrong with this snippet of code? Every time a value is changed in the specified range (A1:B6), Excel simply quits with Microsoft Error Reporting dialogue. *I am not allowed to uncheck 'Error Checking (Turn on background error checking)' in Excel Preferences.*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:B6")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Call Macro1
        MsgBox "Test"
    End If
End Sub
```

Macro1:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rInterestCell As Range
    Dim rDest As Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDest = wb.Sheets("Formula Results")

    For Each rInterestCell In Range("Interest_Range").Cells
        wsData.Range("A7").Value = rInterestCell.Value  
        wsData.Calculate    
        Set rDest = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        If rDest.Row < 6 Then Set rDest = wsDest.Range("A6")   
        rDest.Value = wsData.Range("A6").Value   
    Next rInterestCell

End Sub
```

Second Macro

```
  Sub Macro2()
Dim FLrange As Range
Set FLrange = Range(“Initial_Rate”)

For Each cell In FLrange
cell.Offset(0, 5).Formula = "=SUM(B3/100*A7)”

Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you done as it asks and turned on background error checking? The issue could well be in your Macro1, have you stepped through it with F8 to see on which line it quits?

Comment: Try to add `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the first and `Application.EnableEvents = True` at end.

Comment: Why do you have `Range(Target.Address)` , just use `Target`. No need to have `Call Macro1` just write `Macro1`. For debug part, write `MsgBox "Start"` before `Macro1`, and  `MsgBox "Finish"` after. This way you'll know where the error is coming from

Comment: If I remove .Address from Target, it results in "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed" error. Adding debug part, didn't show any errors, all Macros are executing as intended. The error seems to be random, one time, everything will function with no errors, then suddenly, Excel quits on you.

Comment: @zafira.404 can u share Macro1 ?

Comment: I've added Macro1 to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better turn off events with `Application.EnableEvents = False` before doing so much calculation in `Macro1`.

If this works, just comment `MsgBox "Before Macro1"` and `MsgBox "After Macro1"`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Me.Range("A1:B6")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Before Macro1"
        Macro1
        MsgBox "After Macro1"
    End If
End Sub
```

Macro1:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim wB As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rInterestCell As Range
    Dim rDest As Range

    Set wB = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDest = wB.Sheets("Formula Results")

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each rInterestCell In Range("Interest_Range").Cells
        wsData.Range("A7").Value = rInterestCell.Value
        wsData.Calculate
        DoEvents
        Set rDest = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        If rDest.Row < 6 Then Set rDest = wsDest.Range("A6")
        rDest.Value = wsData.Range("A6").Value
    Next rInterestCell

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Sadly, this didn't help. Could it be my second macro? It worked fine for a few times, and then I changed a cell value under specified Target range and it caused Excel to crash (quit unexpectedly).

Comment: @zafira.404 : It probably is, as the `Worksheet_Change` is pretty neat. Do you have an error or does Excel just crash? Is `Before Macro1` message displayed? Is `After Macro1` message displayed?

Comment: It hasn't shown any of MsgBox', just quits with 'There was a problem and Microsoft Excel was closed. We apologize for the inconvenience' with 'More Information' button with the following log: 
"
Error Signature:
Exception: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
 
and "Crashed thread: 0
uncaught ObjC exception, reason: -[NSAlert runModal] may not be invoked inside of transaction commit (usually this means it was invoked inside of a view's -drawRect: method.)"

Comment: @zafira.404 : If it didn't show any MsgBox, then the issue is coming from the `Worksheet_Change` or another event that is triggered. I'd suggest that you ask another question with this detailed message, specifying that you have [tag:osx] and [tag:excel-vba-mac]

Comment: Thank you for your help, R3uK. :)