# Unknown Error causes Excel Crash

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have an OSX operating system, and I am running Microsoft Excel for Mac.

Either [my macro or worksheet_change event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42248504/4628637) (which has no syntax errors or bugs) causes excel to quit unexpectedly with

> 'Microsoft Error Reporting'

when I try to change the value in Target range I've specified in worksheet_change event.

Here is the detailed log of occurred error. Can someone explain what causes the crash by looking at the log?

```
Microsoft Error Reporting log version: 2.0

Error Signature:
Exception: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
Exception Code: 0x00000001 (0x0000000111ba94c1)
Date/Time: 2017-02-15 15:30:02 +0000
Application Name: Microsoft Excel
Application Bundle ID: com.microsoft.Excel
Application Signature: XCEL
Application Bitness: x64
Application Version: 15.30.0.170107
Crashed Module Name: CoreFoundation
Crashed Module Version: 6.9.0
Crashed Module Offset: 0x000000000011148b
Blame Module Name: CocoaUI
Blame Module Version: 1.0.0.0
Blame Module TimeStamp: 0x5870d060
Blame Module Offset: 0x000000000005d1ad
StackHash: ffffbecc
Application LCID: 1033
Extra app info: Reg=en Loc=0x0409
Crashed thread: 0
uncaught ObjC exception, reason: -[NSAlert runModal] may not be invoked inside of transaction commit (usually this means it was invoked inside of a view's -drawRect: method.)

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffad88748b __exceptionPreprocess + 171 
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffc1fe9cad objc_exception_throw + 48 
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffad90596d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205 
3   AppKit                              0x00007fffabca29da _NSRunModal + 266 
4   AppKit                              0x00007fffab7509b9 -[NSAlert runModal] + 270 
5   CocoaUI                             0x0000000112dec1ad CUIAlertRunModal + 78 
6   MicrosoftOffice                     0x00000001103f2952 
...etc.

Operating System Information
Operating System: Mac OS X 10.12.1 (Build 16B2555)
CPU: Intel x86, Logical CPU Count: 4, Frequency: 2600 MHz
Physical Memory: 8192 MB
Device: x86_64
Screen: 1680.000000 x 1050.000000, bitsPerPixel = 24, frame = 0.000000, 0.000000, 1680.000000, 1050.000000

Microsoft Application Information:
Error Reporting UUID: 063833AD-3543-4B60-8823-2F16D072A69E
ULS UUID: 726769E8-C159-4489-8556-54B791CFCFCD
Rules Engine Session ID: 726769E8-C159-4489-8556-54B791CFCFCD
Time from launch: 0 hours, 52 minutes, 5 seconds
Total errors on this client: 42
Crashed App Virtual Memory Size: 4173.132
Crashed App Resident Memory Size: 447.5742
```

Comment: Sorry I can't give you the answer but for what it's worth, Excel for mac crashes on me all the time when I'm testing perfectly fine VBA code

Comment: I don't do MAC VBA, so this is all just a guess.  `[NSAlert runModal] may not be invoked inside of transaction commit (usually this means it was invoked inside of a view's -drawRect: method.)` implies to me that the problem may be the displaying of the message box ( a modal dialog) while the screen is being updated.  Try either removing the message box code or trying applying `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` if it is supported.